# Is anyone aware of any score keeping apps (BB10 or Android) that can keep track of score (including extra meta-data)?

Tags: scoring

I know there are lots of apps (eg: keepscore, scorekeeper, endless variations of those words) that can keep a simple tally for various players for generic games. I am looking for one that can:

- Keep track of current scores, for players and/or teams.
- I would like to be able to track bids for current rounds of many card games, eg: spades, bidwhist.

BONUS:

- Keep histories of specific players, win records, stats, etc...
- Integrate a dice and or timer.
- Somewhere to track custom meta-data. For example bidwhist, has a rotating trump suit. I can jot down, Round 1=Spades, 2=H,3=C,4=D, 5=NoTrump, etc...

I had an IOS app that did some of this, but have yet to find an Android, or BB10 app. Does anyone know of or use one? I hate having to dig up a notepad.

Comment: Voting to close this as too broad. "Can track meta-data" includes a _crazily huge_ number of concepts, not all of which are handled equally, and not all of which is recorded simply or easily without the app specialising in particular games. Please define _the type_ of metadata. Rather than trying to search for a single uber-app for all games (likely impractical), it's probably worthwhile to just make separate recommendations for apps for specific games.

Comment: I gave an example of what I was looking for, but I can clarify further if that helps.

Comment: He's pretty much asking about tracking trick-taking style card games, which is specific enough.

Comment: This is better asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

My friends and I use [rankade](http://rankade.com), which has an app both for iOS and Android (but I prefer the webapp, personally, as it has the graphs). You can use it for every game, and the thing I like the most is the fact that it gives you the whole history (and rankings) for both the group (collective matches) and for each single boardgame. I don't think it can track every single metadata you're asking, though.

Answer (score 2):

I use two different apps that give you a majority of what you are looking for.  I have an Android device, and I use Gamekeeper (free version) and the Board Game Geek app.

Gamekeeper allows me to keep track of scores, add dice (of any size and quantity with modifiers), and it also has a timer.  You could potentially add additional rows to the scores area to track some meta data such as bids (anything that is a numeric quantity).

With the Board Game Geek app, it's a lot more than just logging plays.  It allows you track your collection, log plays, track players who played, date played, who won, final scores, how long it took to play, etc.  You do have to go to boardgamegeek.com to manage your collection.  Right now you still can't add new games to your collection directly within the app.  However, outside of that the app is still a phenomenal thing to use, and it's a great way to track your historical plays.

Answer (score 1):

I never found on that I really loved, so I wrote my own and published it. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keep-score-game-keeper/id1140300229?mt=8

Answer (score -2):

Hands down the best for Spades scoring is RenegeAid on Android.  [www.renegeaid.com](http://www.renegeaid.com)
We play a lot of spades and made this for serious Spades players since we couldn't find any other app that did it right.

Comment: Your profile says you're an app developer; can you disclose whether this app is or isn't yours? It's fine to recommend your own apps, but our [spam policy](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) suggests people should disclose their relationship to products they suggest, if they have one.

Comment: Yes, we do use our own products as well as others, that's why we stand behind it.  I've updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: OP is looking for something that works for "generic games" - your app appears to only be for Spades.

Comment: @BJMyers the description of talon8's question clearly states "I would like to be able to track bids for current rounds of many card games, eg: spades, bidwhist" - indicating heavy interest in Spades and Spades-like games that include bidding.  We still stand behind our answer.